# Do export sanctions prevent web services or websites?

Tags: united-states, russian-federation, sanctions, internet

If the United States has economic sanctions against Russia, does this prevent American companies from serving websites to users in Russia? Will Google, Youtube, etc., have to be made inaccessible in Russia? If not, why not? Aren't they "exporting" information along data cables?

Comment: This is hard to answer since the situation (and specific sanctions levied) are constantly changing. Are you asking if this is banned under current sanctions? Under sanctions under discussion? Or whether it's legally possible for the US to implement sanctions that do this?

Comment: I guess I thought that the current sanctions banned exporting anything to Russia? So I guess I was asking the first question, but if the answer is "no" I'd be interested in the other two as well.

Answer (score 2):

By its very nature, the internet doesn't do well with geographical boundaries. Requests are routed from server to server. There are some ways to do [geoblocking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geo-blocking), but they are just an afterthought on the original protocols. A **web server** just gets requests from an IP, it cannot tell if that is a [proxy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_server).

So when governments want to regulate internet services, they go after the **business relationships**, like advertising or customer subscriptions. The problem with google and facebook is that their customers usually do not pay *directly*, they pay by having their personal data collected and getting advertising directed at them. A government might prohibit those companies from accepting Russian advertising, or from having Russian subsidiaries. Anything beyond that is difficult.

Russia might have a slightly easier time blocking incoming traffic, but *selectively* blocking outgoing traffic to Russia is impractical unless one cuts of all internet connections to Russia, and to *all* countries which do not block Russia as well. Compare how [North Korea](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telecommunications_in_North_Korea#International_Internet_access) gets to the world-wide web.

Comment: This is a good explanation for why it's hard to do such blocking. Am I correctly reading an implication that the sanctions don't require companies to try?

Comment: As I understand this, the proposed sanctions would hit at business relationships (no SWIFT, no contracts), but they do not prohibit sending media content to Russia.